If the encoding circuit for a quantum code is a Clifford operation then the logical pauli errors correspond to pauli physical errors?
I was reading Lecture $2$ from M2 ICEP- Quantum Information Theory (https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/omar.fawzi/teaching/qit-paris/lecture_notes/QEC-lec2.pdf). I am a little confused on the reasoning for the following statement:
"The fact that the encoding circuit of a stabilizer code is a Clifford operation is particularly useful because it implies that logical Pauli errors correspond to Pauli physical errors."
I think I understand that logical Pauli errors are errors which map logical states to other logical states.
Physical Pauli errors are errors which map physical Pauli states to other physical Pauli states.
The fact that they correspond to each other means that a logical error that changes $L_{1} \rightarrow L_{2}$, then the physical error $P_{i}$ (obtained by applying the encoding Clifford $U$ to the logical operation $L_{i}$) changes the physical state $P_{1} \rightarrow P_{2}$.
However, I don't understand exactly why this follows from the fact that the encoding circuit is a Clifford operation. Is this because the Clifford group is the automorphism group of the Pauli group? Does the fact that the Clifford group is the automorphism group of the Pauli group mean that for $U \in$ Clifford group and $E_{n}$ being the Pauli group on $n$ qubits: $$UE_{n}U^{\dagger} = E_{n}?$$
Then, is the encoding circuit defined by $U L_{i} = P_{i}$ (i.e. Clifford operation $U$ encodes logical state into physical state?)?
I can't quite get to the conclusion that the fact that the encoding circuit is a clifford operation implies that logical pauli errors correspond to pauli physical errors?
